# Bash Scripting: Parse File Contents Into Array

Tags: bash

Greetings,

I'm writing a simple bash script that needs to parse the contents of a file into an array.  Entries in the file are "newline" delimited -- so the file would look something like this:

```
path/to/file
path/to/other/file
```

I'd like to parse in the contents and iterate over them.  My code currently looks like:

```
CONTENT=`cat /path/to/text/file.txt`
for PATH in $CONTENT
do
   echo $PATH
   chmod -R 440 $PATH
fi
```

This code works great with a file with UNIX line-endings.   With a windows formatted text file, however, it chokes miserably.   The "echo $PATH" statement produces the correct path, but the chmod fails saying that the file doesn't exist.   My knack is that the Windows line-endings aren't getting trimmed, so its trying to chmod a file-path that includes a new line character.

I need to make this thing work regardless of whether the target file was created with Unix or Windows newlines -- but given I am somewhat new to shell scripting I'm not all that sure how to do it.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to remove the carriage return when processing each line.  The real easy way is to use the `dos2unix` utility, but if your system doesn't have that or you can't get it, you can accomplish similar things with `tr`, e.g:

`echo $PATH | tr -d '\r'`

More ideas, such as using `sed`, are available on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) entry.

**EDIT:**  I should point out that `$PATH` is not a great variable name, since it is undoubtedly set by the environment and other programs may depend on its value.  You should consider changing it to something like `$CUR_PATH`.

Comment: @Skone: no problemo

Answer (score 3):

I'd just change the first line of the script:

`CONTENT=$(tr -d \\r < /path/to/text/file.txt)`